# Density of states for fermions - Statistical Mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, density-of-states

I'm studying about the density of states $g(k)$ of fermions at the moment and its equations, but I'm confused about the following:

[image]

This is an equation given in the notes for the course, where $N$ is the total number of particles in the system, $g_{s}$ is the spin density, $V$ is the volume of the D-dimensional system (D = 1,2,3...) and $k$ is the wavenumber.

$n_{k}^{(F)}$ is the Fermi distribution: $n_{k}^{(F)} = \frac{1}{e^{\beta(...)}+1}$ as seen in the 2nd line of Eq. (0.36).

The notes then give the following equations calculated for different dimensions (D values):

[image]

However, when I try to go from Eq. (0.36) to Eq. (0.37) myself, I keep getting stuck. For example, why is it not $(2\pi)^2$ for $D=2$?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It's not $(2\pi)^2$ for $D=2$ because one factor of $2\pi$ gets canceled by the angular integration in the numerator...

Answer (score 2):

> [image]

Please use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) instead of screenshots for equations. (If I try to answer a question with screenshots, I can not edit the screenshots to copy and modify the equations. This makes answering harder.) Anyways, I will re-write this equation in MathJax for you:
$$
N = g_s V \int \frac{d^D k}{(2\pi)^D}n_k^{(F)}
$$
$$
\equiv\int dk g(k)n_k^{(F)}\;.
$$

And therefore, by remembering that $d^{D}k = dk k^{(D-1)}d\Omega_D$, we see:
$$
g(k) = g_s V k^{(D-1)}\int \frac{d\Omega_D}{(2\pi)^D}\;,
$$
where $d\Omega_D$ is my notation for the differential [solid angle in $D$ dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Solid_angles_in_arbitrary_dimensions). E.g., $d\Omega_2 = d\phi$, where $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$. E.g., $d\Omega_3=d\phi d\theta \sin(\theta)$, where $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$.

> The notes then give the following equations calculated for different dimensions (D values):
>
> [image]
>
> However, when I try to go from Eq. (0.36) to Eq. (0.37) myself, I keep getting stuck. For example, why is it not $(2\pi)^2$ for $D=2$?
>
> How would I go about doing this?

You need to remember the volume element in D = 1, 2, and 3 dimensions. Then you need to remember how to write it in spherical coordinates.

I'm not going to work all these out for you, since I'd feel like I'm doing your homework for you, but I'll do $D=2$:
$$
g(k) = g_s V k\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\phi}{(2\pi)^2} 
= g_s V k\frac{2\pi}{(2\pi)^2}
= \frac{g_s V k}{2\pi}\;,
$$
where you can see that *one* of the $2\pi$ factors in the denominator is cancelled by the integration over $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ in the numerator.